# Recent viewed product conflcit with infiniteScroll

Tags: magento2, products, recently-viewed, infinte-scroll

I have installed the Infinite scroll extension On my category Listing page.
I have also added the feature of recent viewed product, but it not compatible with infinite scoll. 
I have done the changes in the layout `catalog_category.view.xml`

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="recentview.products" template="Magento_Theme::recentProduct.html" after="category.products" />
```

Comment: Please, add your infinite scroll extension name. And tell us what is your issue?

Comment: I have added the amasty Infinite scroll. I have to show the recent viewed product at the last when all the pages is load

Comment: @Divya, is the paid extension?